# Is the following big-o notation equivalent to each other?

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

### **O[ ((1/n)*(log<sub>2</sub>n)<sup>2</sup> + 1/√n) * ( √nlog<sub>3</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>n) + √nlog<sub>2</sub>n ) ] = O [ (log n)<sup>3</sup>/√n ]**

Is the above Big O notation equivalent to each other? I expanded the left side out (not shown here) and it seems that  [(log n)<sup>3</sup>/√n]  is the highest power.

If they are equivalent to each other, is there a simpler way of finding out why? Because I think expanding the left side out is too much work.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting, I tried my best to format

Comment: This might be more of a math question than a programming one.  I would ask on [math.se], and I believe the [asymptomatics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics) tag might be appropriate there.

Comment: [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) may be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @Amy do you know how to change this question to the Math.SE?

Comment: In particular, on Math.SE you can use LaTeX/Mathjax formatting, which would make it much easier to read.

Comment: The two terms in the right factor have a common factor of sqrt(n). Moving this to the left produces ((log2 n)^2/sqrt(n) + 1)•(log3 log2 n + log2 n). Then (log2 n)^2/sqrt(n) approaches zero as n grows. So (log2 n)^2/sqrt(n) + 1 approaches 1, and the expression is effectively log3 log2 n + log2 n, so it should be O(log2 n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: ((1/n)*(log<sub>2</sub>n)<sup>2</sup> + 1/√n) can be replaced with just 1/√n, because the rest is much smaller for large n, while ( √nlog<sub>3</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>n) + √nlog<sub>2</sub>n ) becomes √nlog<sub>2</sub>n for the same reason, so in the end you have 1/√n * √nlog<sub>2</sub>n, which is just log<sub>2</sub>n.

Comment: So for each of the two expressions on the left, you find the highest power of each expression and then finally find the higher expression among the two remaining powers 1/√n * √nlog2n, ?

Comment: @hcoder75: General rules are dangerous in this; limits can be complicated.

Comment: @hcoder75 no, I find the largest of the expressions in left sum, ignore the rest, then the largest of the expressions in the right sum, then multiply the results. you can only ignore expressions when they are added to each other, essentially removing all unimportant ones. however, you have to multiply everything -- you cannot ignore the factors.

Answer (score 0):

No. In the factor (1/n)•(log<sub>2</sub>n)<sup>2</sup> + 1/sqrt(n), the right term, 1/sqrt(n) dominates.

Comment: But I thought the highest power is the thing you put in the brackets of Big O. 1/sqrt(n) is n raised to the power of -1/2, so isn't this less than the logn^3/sqrt(n)

Comment: @hcoder75: “Highest power” is an excessive simplification. Effectively, the division by n makes that a negative power—(log2 n)^2/n is not log2 n to the second power. The (log2 n)^2 is more than canceled by the n, so it goes to zero.